# How do you tokenise a list of strings from a dataframe in Python and have the count of unique words and pairs of words and so fourth in a new df?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a list of strings and I am trying to get a dataframe from this list where I can see each consecutive group of words, the count of occurrences that the list has of the word or group of words, and the number of words in that string as shown below.

| UniqueWords | Count | WordCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | 2 | 1 |
| Mr. | 1 | 1 |
| Smith | 1 | 1 |
| ---------- | ---- | --------- |
| Hello World | 1 | 2 |

I have attempted this using the nltk library in Python but I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize

example_text1 = "Hello Mr. Smith, how are you doing today? The weather is good and Python is awesome. 
The sky is pinkish-blue. You should not eat cardboard."
example_text2 = "Hello World"
example_text3 = "I will go to the kitchen and start making food. Now!"
example_text = [example_text1,example_text2,example_text3]


words_list = pd.DataFrame()
unique_words_list = pd.DataFrame()
unique_words_df = pd.DataFrame()

# My attempt to get the words into a list
for i in range(len(example_text)):
    word_tokens = word_tokenize(example_text[i])
    words_list = words_list.append(word_tokens)
    
# My attempt to put it back into a dataframe
unique_words_list["UniqueWords"] = list(set(words_list[0]))

# My attempt to iterate over the list to get the count in the original list of strings
for j in range(len(unique_words_list["UniqueWords"])):
    print(list(words_list[0]).count(unique_words_list.iloc[j] 
       ["UniqueWords"]),unique_words_list.iloc[j]["UniqueWords"])
```

I am new to the nltk library and I am not sure if it is the best way to get the result that I need. Any help will be great.
Thanks,
CMC

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that creates dataframes that show the frequency of words in a string and the total number of words in a string.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display
from nltk import FreqDist
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

example_text1 = "Hello Mr. Smith, how are you doing today? The weather is good and Python is awesome. The sky is " \
                "pinkish-blue. You should not eat cardboard. "

words_list = pd.DataFrame()
sentence_counts = pd.DataFrame()

# create frequency distribution for a string
freqDist = FreqDist(word_tokenize(example_text1))

# move words and word counts from frequency distribution to lists to fill a dataframe
tokens = []
frequencies = []
for token in freqDist:
    tokens.append(token)
    frequencies.append(freqDist[token])

# fill dataframe with lists
# this dataframe shows the number of times a word occurs in a string
words_list['token'] = tokens
words_list['frequency'] = frequencies
display(words_list)

# this dataframe shows how many words a string contains
sentence_counts['string'] = [example_text1]
sentence_counts['words'] = [freqDist.N()]
display(sentence_counts)
```

Documentation
FreqDist class: https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html